# Comparing and then appending rows to csv file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to compare two columns from *result.csv* and *street_segments.csv* and then if they are the same append columns from *street_segments.csv* to *results.csv*.

```
import csv
count=0
count1=0
count2=0
first = file('result.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(first)

second=file('street_segments.csv', 'rU')
reader1= csv.reader(second)
for row1 in reader1:
        count +=1
        print count
        for row in reader:
            count1 += 1
            print count1
            if row[3]==row1[1]:
                row.append(row1[2])
                row.append(row1[3])
                row.append(row1[4])
                count2 += 1
                print count2
```

The issue that I am having is that what I get is:

```
1 (from count)
1 (from count1)
2 (from count1)
3(from count1)
...
200,000(from count1)
2(from count)
3(from count)
...
90000(from count)
```

With the nested for loops, shouldn't I be getting:

```
1 (from count)
1 (from count1)
2(from count1)
...
90000(from count1)
2 (from count)
1 (from count1)
2(from count1)
...
90000(from count1)
3 (from count)
1(from count1)
2(from count1)
...
90000(from count1)
```

Can you guys let me know what I am doing wrong or if there is a better approach to this problem.

So my results.csv file has a row like:

```
-73.88637197,   40.85400596,    5327502,    P-089988,   1015684.082,    250435.3,   NO PARKING (SANITATION BROOM SYMBOL) 8:30-10AM TUES & FRI <----->
```

and my street_segments.csv has a row:

```
B,  P-004958,   RANDALL AVENUE, FAILE STREET,   COSTER STREET,  N
```

So what I am trying to do is that if the fourth column of results.csv and the second column of street_segments.csv are the same.  I want to add columns 3, 4,5 of street_segments.csv to the end of the row of results.csv.

Comment: Why don't you try appending '(from count)' and '(from count1)' to your print strings to help you (and us) debug?

Comment: Ok done. Yeah sorry about that should have done it in the first place.

Comment: Check your indentation? The output indicates that you're iterating successively.

Comment: The indentation looks to be correct.  Also, I made a mistake when I edited it originally. Can you check it again.  It seems like the first for loop isn't iterating correctly.

Comment: Oh, just caught it, took me a while, sorry... Added an answer. Also I'm not sure that your code is doing what you expect -- do you want to compare the values in each column by row, or compare **all** of the values in *result.csv* to **all** of the values in *street_segments.csv*?

Comment: Haha I'm sure its not.  I'm trying to compare all of the values result.csv to all the values in street_segments.csv in a certain column and if they are the same append street_segments.csv to results.csv.

Comment: Right, but what do you mean "all" of the values? Do you mean "if the values *in each row* are the same, then append to that row", or do you mean "if *every* value in the column over the entire file is the same, then append values to every row"? Or even "if a value in `result` is found *anywhere* in `street_segments`, then append a value"?

Comment: Ok sorry I wasn't explaining it well. I edited the original question.

Comment: In that case, since you want to do row-by-row comparisons, a nested `for` loop is *really*, **really**, **_really_** slowing things down. What you should instead do is remove your inner `for` loop, using `row = reader.next()` in its place -- this way you're iterating simultaneously over both files. You can re-use the existing code inside the inner `for` if you change the indentation level (you'll have to ensure that *that* code is doing what you want, though, I'm done for the night.

Comment: I figured it out. The reader.next() tip really helped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that file iterators do not automatically "rewind". That is, when you hit your second iteration of the outer `for` loop, the inner `for` is never entered, because the file pointer for `reader` (from `first`) is at the end of the file. To solve this you'll need to add a `first.seek(0)` command to get you back to the start of the file (before your inner loop).

```
import csv
count=0
count1=0
count2=0
first = file('result.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(first)

second=file('street_segments.csv', 'rU')
reader1= csv.reader(second)
for row1 in reader1:
        count +=1
        print count
        # Rewind to the start of the file in preparation for the next loop
        first.seek(0)
        for row in reader:
            count1 += 1
            print count1
            if row[3]==row1[1]:
                row.append(row1[2])
                row.append(row1[3])
                row.append(row1[4])
                count2 += 1
                print count2
```

Comment: Updated with an example... Also please see my last comment on your question, I'm not convinced this code is doing what you expect.